# How and why to downgrade libwayland-client++0 libwayland-cursor++0 in Debian10?

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, wayland

On one of my Debian10/KDE machines the package manager or `sudo apt-get upgrade` asks me to downgrade libwayland-client++0 and libwayland-cursor++0. They are installed from Debian backports and of version 0.2.8-1. When confirming the downgrade it installs version 0.2.8-1 and afterwards still asks to downgrade them. Why is this happening? It is only occurring on one of my machines and not on another with almost the same setup and where also 0.2.8-1 is installed from backports. If they should be downgraded how to do so?

I'm using [Basil Gello's repo for Kodi19 on Debian10](https://basilgello.github.io/kodi-nightly-debian-repo/) which is likely associated with this problem but probably not the cause itself as I'm using this same repo on the other machine too. Previously pulseaudio was somehow removed and I could not reinstall it. Now it's installed and running but [audio output without headphones still doesn't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/652621/how-to-enable-audio-output-with-pulseaudio-when-it-is-running). This may be related to the problem.

Output of `apt policy` [here](https://pastebin.com/xKykbwqA) (all other repos have 500 set like the one example).

Comment: btw: 0.2.8-1 is bullseye's version. Debian backports' is 0.2.8-1~bpo10+1 . I hope that was a typo, else that means bullseye was involved in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By running `apt policy` I noticed that Basil Gello had 1 set on the machine on where it doesn't ask me to downgrade these packages and 500 set on the one that prompts about downgrading them.

I simply reran the setup steps for Basil Gello's repo and now this prompt doesn't show anymore.